# Rails 2 call from one model to another is slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, performance

In Rails 2, I'm trying to optimize the performance of a web page the loads slowly.

I'm timing the execution time of statements in a model and finding that a surprising amount of the time is in a call from inside one model to another model, even though it appears there is no database access at all.

To be specific, let's say the model that is slow is department, and I'm calculating Department.expenditures. The expenditures method needs to know whether the quarter has been closed, and that information is in a different model, Quarter

The first time that Department.expenditures calls Quarter.closed? there is a database access, and I can accept that. But I've done something so to keep that in memory inside the  model method, so that future calls to Quarter.closed? have no database access. The code inside Quarter.closed? now runs in around 4 microseconds, but simply invoking Quarter.closed? from inside Department.expenditures takes 400 microseconds, and with hundreds of departments, that adds up.

I could cache the Quarter.closed value inside a global variable, but that seems hairy. Does anyone know what is going on or have a suggestion about a better practice?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this applies to your problem. But with similar loading time problems in many cases eager loading solves the problem. You would do it like this:

```
Department.all(:include => :expenditures)
```

I'm a bit out of Rails 2 syntax. In Rails 3 you can specify includes quite detailed like this:

```
Category.includes(:posts => [{:comments => :guest}, :tags]).find(1)
```

I think (but not sure) the :include option in Rails 2 allowed for similar syntax
So maybe this would work:

```
Department.all(:include => [:expenditures => [:quarters]])
```

(Maybe need some experiments with combination of arra/hash syntax here)